# How can I make everything relate to background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project and got stuck. I have a background image which is 16:9 ratio.

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
//for example:

.inventory {
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5);
  top: 28%;
  left: 18%;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 19%;
  height: 55.6%;
  overflow: auto;
  position:fixed
}
```

What I want now is, that when I decrease the size of the window everything stays on its position and has its relative height and width. The problem I am facing at the moment is, that everything I position with percentage is related to the size of the window. But i want to make everything relate to the size of the image.
Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Just to ensure I understand the question:  are you trying to maintain a 16:9 aspect ratio for your site layout, regardless of the size / aspect ratio of the browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a locked aspect ratio for something, `padding` allows for this because it's always relative to an element's width. In this example, you'd set your `background-image` to replace `background: green;` and place all of your content inside that `container-inner` div

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.container-inner {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `background-image` you will need to set the `height` of that element. If you resize the window the `width` will change according to window but `height` will be fix resulting background image size will increase and in that case you can't control the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` values of position...

So you will need to use a `img` instead of a `background-image` here...and use `position:absolute` to place the items over image having `%` values not `px`...remember to set `position:relative` to its parent container

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.parent .spot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900">
  <div class="spot"></div>
</div>
```

Try to edit **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/8hjLm4qs/1/)** here